# Use vertex property value to create edge when traversing multiple vertex programatically

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I find that when importing data into the graph from a DB or any format in which I have a relationships as column keys, I have the need to create Edges using these keys which are already properties in the vertex.

How can I go through all Vertices creating Edges by using these FKs that I already ingested into the graph?

And I need this to be doable programmatically, because I have a lot of data where this step is required. Currently I'm using Gremlin.Net because the majority of the code I use is already C#

Example:
Imagine I have ingested some customers

> g.addV('customer').property('id', c_id).property('product', product_id)

And some products

> g.addV('product').property('id', product_id)

I want to create edges like: costumer[bought-> project]
How can I use the ids to create edges?
I can't seem to be able to reference a property in the context of its vertex.

I want to do something like:

> g.V.hasLabel('customer').as('c').addE('bought').to(g.V(c.product))

Obviously I cannot do `c.product`, and if there is any solution using loops, sadly it's out of the question since Cosmos Graph does not support it.

So far I've been resorting to looping in C# but even my sample data is not scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a nicer way to do this, but I'll offer this:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV('customer').property('id', 321).property('productBought', 123)
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.addV('product').property('id', 123)
==>v[3]
gremlin> g.addV('customer').property('id', 987).property('productBought', 789)
==>v[5]
gremlin> g.addV('product').property('id', 789)
==>v[8]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('customer').as('c').
......1>   V().hasLabel('product').as('p').
......2>   where('p', eq('c')).
......3>     by('id').
......4>     by('productBought').
......5>   select('p').
......6>   addE('buys').from('c').to('p')
==>e[10][0-buys->3]
==>e[11][5-buys->8]
```

That concept above is somewhat based on "traversal induced values" which is described [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#traversal-induced-values) in more detail.

I've seen a lot of questions lately that are asking this sort of question - where people want to do joins without edges (i.e. joins on vertex property values). That's not a place where graph queries shine and for most implementations of Gremlin, likely CosmosDB as well, this will be an expensive operation depending on how much data you have.

Edges are best generated when knowledge of the relationship is known. So, if you knew at one point that "productBought" existed then it should not have been loaded as a "productBought" property key but as an edge to a "product" vertex. Making these kinds of choices up front in you schema design will save a lot of difficulty later.

Comment: Thanks, I think this can get me started, thought it looks like a very expensive operation. As for your comment, the graph is not my source of truth, I have tons of preexisting data with multiple relationships, some of which is not easy to query, so I cannot load 50+ vertices at once with all the edges in place. I would think this to be a common scenario, as almost no one would think to first start with a graph. But considering that one of the strengths is supposed to be relationships, I'm stunned to find that it is so hard to accomplish

Comment: Graphs are meant to emphasize relationships and they are explicit by edges. Doing joins on properties is treating the graph like a relational data store and when that happens the query is typically expensive as you are giving up the most precious aspect of the graph - the direct connection between entities via the link between them. So, what you are doing is not really a common scenario at all. Someone on the gremlin-users mailing list just moments ago went so far as to say that "join" patterns this should never be used: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/H-_1olyYPkA/uS0Zng77BAAJ

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you can't load vertices with edges in place. No matter how many data sources you have I would think that the problem could be mitigated with a clear schema design followed by appropriate data staging prior to load to the graph.

Comment: It has a lot to do with the complexity of my data and the fact that I'm not starting from zero, I want the graph as way to do what is otherwise extremely expensive in a relational model, which is to traverse relationships. As I load data in the graph (coming from other places like sql, mongodb, json blobs, you name it) this operation of deriving edges from properties would come less often. And I did try that approach, but the sheer amount of data, relationships and validations I have to add get ridiculous pretty fast.

Comment: Also, I hope I don't have to assume that my schema has to remain forever static. While some new relationships will arise as we evolve the project, and thus can be ingested alongside newer vertices, the most interesting ones for us are those that we could derive from the data, and here is where I would need again to build edges based on properties. Without this ability, I think I might want to look elsewhere in my search for relationship creation and traversal.

Comment: The graph doesn't need to stay static and the graph data model can certainly evolve over time. I don't mean to give the impression otherwise. You just have have the right expectation with respect to traversals that basically have to touch the entire graph. Global operations with graphs will be costly. You typically perform such operations in a parallel distributed fashion with Gremlin Spark (not sure what options exist with CosmosDB).

Comment: I don't mean to belabor the point, but I'll add that for those "interesting ones" that you "derive from the data" itself - I usually see those come as a result of traversing edges that you've added to the graph and not by doing vertex to vertex joins. Those interesting, newly derived bits of data will form new vertex/edge structures connected to what you already had in the graph and that is definitely a common/expected practice in your graph's growth.